# Insert INTO not working

Tags: php, sql

I have a problem with SQL syntax. I have 2 tables and the third table is generated in SQL Workbench (n:m relationship).

My 3rd table has 2 columns `product_id` and `categories_id`.

I use this SQL in php my admin to add a new row:

```
INSERT INTO `products_has_categories` (`products_id`, `categories_id`) 
VALUES ('17', '1');
```

if phpmyadmin, the sql add a new row, with product_id = 17 and categories_id =1.

My problem:

i have a simple php file called test.php looking like:

```
 $connection = mysqli_connect("andrei.local","andrei94ro","masina", "intership");

if(!$connection)
{
    echo 'error';
}
$query =  "INSERT INTO `products_has_categories` (`products_id`, `categories_id`) VALUES ('17', '1');";
```

or

```
$query =  "INSERT INTO `products_has_categories` (`products_id`, `categories_id`) VALUES ('17', '1')";
```

When i run test.php file, the code not working, and no adding new row in SQL table.
Can u help me?

Comment: Are you checking for errors?  Perhaps the row is already there and duplicates are not allowed.

Comment: Check spelling of your column names or table name

Comment: no duplicates and i copy the sql code from the phpmyadmin. i try 3 differeces sql syntax.. i dont know why is not working

Comment: the sql syntax work on phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I'm concerned, you're not even calling `query()`.

Try this:

```
$connection = new mysqli("andrei.local","andrei94ro","masina", "intership");

if(!$connection)
{
    echo 'error';
} else {
    $query = $connection->query("INSERT INTO `products_has_categories`     (`products_id`, `categories_id`) VALUES ('17', '1')");
}
```